# I want to make a english word-meaning dictionary as a file/folder, what will be the most efficient way to access it?

Tags: performance, file, memory

So i want to make a dictionary and there are two ways i can think of accomplishing this

1. a dictinary directory where each word is stored as a filename with its meaning as the filecontent
2. a single file with all words

First question can someone suggest any better way to store a dictionary which is efficient ? (i have to store this as a file)

Second question which of 2 methods suggested by me is more faster to access ?

Please note i am not going to search through this directory since it will be huge rather only check if the word exists or not by checking if the file exists and then print its content if its exists.

Edit: added how am i going to use the dictionary as suggested by @Vlad Feinstein

Comment: The title is self-contradictionary ...when trying to provide efficiency to something which clearly isn't efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important part is missing from your question: how are you going to use that dictionary?

However, in order to access words stored in individual files you would have to use OS-provided API, that is most likely less efficient that to go through data in a single file.

Please note that many words have multiple meanings. Did you consider some popular data formats, like JSON, to store all that?

Comment: "many words have multiple meanings" @Vlad Feinstein
i am using # to seprate meaning in the file so if a word has multiple meanings its file would have 2 or more # in the content of the file. I might use json to store the values in the files but since the meaning is not that complex for now i am using just #

Comment: "how are you going to use that dictionary ?" for example there is a file called convicted.word with meaning in its content then i can use something like cat convicted.word on unix, i am not going to search through this directory since it will be huge rather only check if the word exists or not, i added this to the question thanks.

Comment: I looked into JSON and found the answer so i will mark this as solved